# How to create a css directive in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, less

I am trying to move styles for a number of elements from a less file into an angular directive. I have created directives already but am unclear how this should be done.

For example, if I have a html file like below:

```
   <div mylessDirective>
       <div class="style1">Hello World</div>
       <div class="style2">Hello World2</div>
       <div class="style3">Hello World3</div>
   <div>
```

Here I have 3 divs with 3 different styles, style 1 and style 2 and style 3. Is it possible to call a directive (mylessDirective) as shown that contains all the less styles associated with this class, so that it picks them up. If so can anyone suggest how this directive should be done, for example if I wanted to set a different background colour for each of the three styles. Thanks for the help!

Comment: less/css is the appropriate tool for that. Why would you need a directive? Just define all the CSS styles that a style1 element must have into the style1 class definition in your less/css stylesheet.

Comment: Also note that Less code must be compiled to CSS before it can be understood by a browser. So unless Angular has built-in ability to compile Less  you can't use *Less* code inside those directives (only plain CSS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if I understood well but I think this is a good approach to the general issue about directive and CSS styling:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/Lpmk2qfo/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div myless-directive>
       <div ng-style="style1">Hello World</div>
       <div ng-style="style2">Hello World2</div>
       <div ng-style="style3">Hello World3</div>
   <div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('mylessDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            scope.style1 = {'background-color': 'red'}; 
            scope.style2 = {'background-color': 'green'}; 
            scope.style3 = {'background-color': 'blue'}; 
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive and construct your own style names:

```
<div>
   <div ng-class="style1">Hello World</div>
   <div ng-class="style2">Hello World2</div>
   <div ng-class="style3">Hello World3</div>
<div>
```